# Getting component name by coordinates on android automation

Tags: java, android, selenium, appium

Getting component name by coordinates on android automation

I want to automate my android application UI using coordinates. Because of measuring perfect position of the component in screen.
I need the result like, If i send `X` and `Y` value the code should return component name(button or text field etc) which is located in the place of given coordinates.

Is it possible to get the component name or whole attributes using coordinates?
Possible means please provide one good example. Please anyone help me on this.

I have build the logic and verified the components with given coordinates. The sample code is given below. But i need to highlight current verifying component, maybe its like a focusing with border colour or arrow icon to indicate above the component.

I have tried with given code for highlight the component but it not works.

private static void highlightElement(WebElement element, RemoteWebDriver driver) {

```
driver = (RemoteWebDriver) driver;
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver; 

js. executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('style', arguments[1]);",
element, "color: yellow; border: 2px solid yellow;");

js.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('style', arguments[1]);"
, element, "");

}
```

} 
Please help on this.

Sample code:

private static String verifyGivenComponentCoordinates(By elementByIdentifier, AndroidDriver driver, String input){
    String coordinateStatus = null;

```
try{
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(elementByIdentifier);

    Point location = element.getLocation();
    int startingXCoordinate = location.getX();
    int startingYCoordinate = location.getY();
    String endingcoordinate = element.getSize().toString();

    endingcoordinate = endingcoordinate.replace("(", "").replace(")", "");

    String[] endingCoordinateArray = endingcoordinate.split(",");
    int endingXCoordinate = startingXCoordinate+Integer.parseInt(endingCoordinateArray[0].trim());
    int endingYCoordinate = startingYCoordinate+Integer.parseInt(endingCoordinateArray[1].trim());

    String startingCoordinateValue = "["+startingXCoordinate+","+startingYCoordinate+"]";
    String endingCoordinateValue = "["+endingXCoordinate+","+endingYCoordinate+"]";

    System.out.println("X coordinate value  ===============> "+startingXCoordinate);
    System.out.println("Y coordinate value  ===============> "+startingYCoordinate);
    System.out.println("Dimention coordinate value  ===============> "+element.getSize());
    System.out.println("Starting Coordinate value  ===============> "+startingCoordinateValue);
    System.out.println("Starting Coordinate value  ===============> "+endingCoordinateValue);

    String caluculatedComponentCoordinate = startingCoordinateValue+endingCoordinateValue;

    System.out.println("Calculated component coordinates =========> "+caluculatedComponentCoordinate);
    if(caluculatedComponentCoordinate.equals(input)){
        System.out.println("Given coordinates matching");
        return coordinateStatus;
    }else{
        System.out.println("Given coordinates does't matching");
        return CommonConstant.COMPONENT_NOT_DISPLAYED;
    }

}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}

return coordinateStatus;
```

}

Comment: yes it is possible.

Comment: Please provide one simple example

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a direct method available for this. But I guess, you can write your own logic where you can find all the elements on the screen, then get the location of each element using `getLocation()` method and then figure out for which control the x,y coordinates fall between the getLocation(). But I'm not sure if this would be a good approach performance-wise.

Comment: Am struggling on focusing element on the screen. Find the sample program on the above question. this is also not working. Anyone please help on this.